# Got ImportError: No module named web

Tags: python

When I run the following `app.py` I get

```
ImportError: No module named web
```

But I've already install `web` with the command `sudo easy_install web.py`, where I got the following:

```
Searching for web.py
Best match: web.py 0.40.dev0
Adding web.py 0.40.dev0 to easy-install.pth file
Using/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for web.py
Finished processing dependencies for web.py
```

then running

```
pip install web.py
```

I got

```
Requirement already satisfied: web.py in/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.40.dev0)
```

still got the the error when running my `app.py`

```
import web

urls=(
  '/','index'
  )

app=web.application(urls,globals())

class index:
    def GET(self):
    greeting="Hello World"
    return greeting

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: May be you run with python2

Comment: Are you using `python3` or `python2` to run the script? Are you sure that `web` is installed in the correct one? If not, have you tried `pip3 install web`?

Comment: I tried python3 bin/app.py                      
     got:Traceback (most recent call last):
 ^
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay, so according to the official website of web.py (webpy.org), pip install web.py will download a version that works only for python2.

in order for you to install web.py for python3 you have to do the following:
pip uninstall web.py

pip install web.py==0.40-dev1

Comment: After input pip install web.py==0.40-dev1,  I got:                                            WARNING: Building wheel for web.py failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/U...
Successfully installed web.py-0.40.dev1
Then I tried :'python  bin/app.py '             still got:no module named web           
 When I try:'python3 bin/app.py                 I got:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cheroot'

Comment: try downloading from, github:  git clone git://github.com/webpy/webpy.git

Comment: It worked when I download from github and installed cheroot with "pip3 install cheroot" Thanks  a lot

Comment: anytime, will you please mark the question answered

Comment: from https://github.com/webpy/webpy command $python3 -m pip install web.py==0.62 worked for me. I am using Python 3.10.4 64bit on windows